# How to return boolean with math expression comparison in Views

Tags: views

I want to output a boolean value like this:

*if some field value (e.g. [comment_count]) > x (my constant, e.g. 5) = 1, else 0*

without installing Views PHP (or other modules) or having to create a field.

I tried with the Views field "Global: math expression" but that won't support comparisons.

Is there a math expression or another simple way to do this within my view?

PS: I thought I could use **floor(logX([comment_count])** but logX() seems not supported: it always returns 0. Custom base logarithm is among PHP math functions but not present in Views? :(

Answer (score 0):

Easiest method is to either use hook views view pre render out a preprocess function.